gl_instanceindex takes location of my vertex input(so, it invalidate smy input for vertex)
Have problem with instanced drawing. gl_instanceindex takes input location of one of my vertex attributes. Why is it happening?
shader inputs:
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 vOctNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 vColor;
layout (location = 3) in vec2 vTexCoord;


I've not seen this before, but it is likely a setup or offset/memory issue.
